# firefox won't scroll wordpress website but works in chrome and ie

Tags: firefox, scroll, scrollbar

Have just implemented a design into wordpress for a client but for some reason the site won't scroll in firefox? any help would be really appreciated Also on this website url it can't find jquery but works fine on my localhost anyone can help?

http://www.modernandclassicautos.co.uk.php53-7.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    font:300 14px/1.4;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    color:#19150b;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0!important;
    background: url(img/background.png) repeat;
}
```

remove overflow:hidden in this class

Comment: A bad question, the example of the problem is no longer available. Nevertheless this answer did help me. My element had a parent with "overflow: hidden", and removing that made scrolling work on the child. Upvoted.